# Ionic Cordova - iOS 12 and 13 pushing footer buttons beyond safe area

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, ionic-framework, ios13

I have an app written in Ionic v1, Cordova, and AngularJS 1.5.3.

The problem that I have does not occur on Android devices at all.

iPhones tested on: iPhone SE, iPhone 8, iPhone X, and iPhone XR.

```
For iOS 13.6 the problem occurs on: iPhone SE, iPhone 8, iPhone X, and iPhone XR.
iPhone X, and iPhone XR ( completely pushes the buttons out of view )

For iOS 12 the problem occurs on:

iPhone XR - somewhat occurs
iPhone 8 - does not occur
iPhone SE - does not occur
iPhone X - somewhat occurs

For iOS 11:
it does not occur on iPhone 8. There are no problems.
iPhone SE - no problems
It somewhat occurs on the iPhone X.
iPhone XR does not run iOS 11.
```

As the version of iOS increases, it seems to have more of an effect.

**What my code is doing:**

My page is for the user to enter an absence and they have the option of adding photo attachments.
The attachment is just going to be added as an ion-item in my ion-list.

I have an ionic view and a footer with a button in it. When I add an ionic item to my ionic list, it seems to push the footer button down out of the "safe area" and it does so permanently.

Even if I go to a different page and come back again the problem persists. It also seems to permanently affect the "safe area" on the different pages of my app.

**Problem:**
As the attachment list grows, it pushes the footer button down out of the safe area

**How can I keep my button in my footer in place on the latest versions of iOS?**

[image]

**Code snippet:**

```
<ion-view left-buttons="leftButtons" cache-view="false" right-buttons="rightButtons">

    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button menu-toggle="right" class="button button-icon icon ion-home" ui-sref="main.home"
            automation-id="RIGHT_NAV_HOME_BUTTON">
        </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>

    <ion-content class="has-header has-footer bg-stable" padding="false">

        <ion-list can-swipe="true">

            <div class="item title-bar">
                <h2 class="dark" ng-i18next="BOOK_ABSENCE"></h2>
            </div>

            <div class="item item-icon-left" ng-click="setDate('startDate')">
                <i class="icon ion-ios-calendar-outline"></i>
                <span ng-i18next="START_DATE"></span>
                <span class="item-note">{{ data.startDate | dateFormat }}</span>
            </div>

            <div class="item item-icon-left" ng-click="setDate('endDate')">
                <i class="icon ion-ios-calendar"></i>
                <span ng-i18next="END_DATE"></span>
                <span class="item-note">{{ data.endDate | dateFormat }}</span>
                <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-right"></i>
            </div>

            <div class="item item-divider"></div>

            <label class="item item-input">
                <textarea placeholder="Comments" ng-model="data.comments" rows="4"></textarea>
            </label>

            <div class="item item-divider"></div>

            <ion-item class="flex-container-center" ng-repeat="attachment in attachments">
                <div class="flex-item-1">
                    <img ng-src="data:{{ attachment.mediaTypeField }};base64,{{ attachment.imageDataField }}">
                </div>
                <div class="flex-item-big">
                    <div>{{ attachment.filename }}</div>
                </div>
            </ion-item>

        </ion-list>

    </ion-content>

    <div class="bar bar-footer no-padding bg-bottom">
        <div class="button-bar">
            <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="book()">
                <span ng-i18next="SAVE"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

</ion-view>
```

**Environment:**

```
ionic info

Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.10.3 (C:\Users\User\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.3.5
   @ionic/v1-toolkit : 1.0.22

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 8.1.0, ios 6.1.0, browser 5.0.4, windows 4.4.3
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 17 other plugins)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\User\Documents\Android\sdk)
   NodeJS            : v10.21.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.14.4
   OS                : Windows 10
```

In the past, the new iPhone X came out and I added some code to make adjustments for the "safe area".

**css**

```
body {
    padding: constant(safe-area-inset-top) constant(safe-area-inset-right) constant(safe-area-inset-bottom) constant(safe-area-inset-left); //iOS 11.2
    padding: env(safe-area-inset-top) env(safe-area-inset-right) env(safe-area-inset-bottom) env(safe-area-inset-left);
}
```

**html**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

As I'm using cordova-ios 6.1.0 I'm using WkWebView only.

```
<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
```

Comment: Maybe it's related to the new webview engine?

Comment: Have you got a solution yet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the `env()` calculation is only reliable when the app first loads. When we open the camera widget, we are technically leaving the application and when we come back the `env()` is evaluated again and it's giving a value that we don't want.

To solve this problem I set the top padding to be zero.

```
body {
    padding: 0 constant(safe-area-inset-right) constant(safe-area-inset-bottom) constant(safe-area-inset-left); //iOS 11.2
    padding: 0 env(safe-area-inset-right) env(safe-area-inset-bottom) env(safe-area-inset-left);
}
```

We already have viewport cover in the HTML so we are good when it comes to the safe area.

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar/issues/156) link pointing towards the same issue ?